# InflateException Error inflating class EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, layout-inflater, inflate-exception

I'm having trouble while inflating on Android Studio.

It's working fine in emulator. Problem however happens I test the app on my phone (an HTC One M7 - the first one).

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/ingcard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/tvrecname"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/etingquantity"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
E/Drive.UninstallOperation: Package still installed jdev.recipehelper
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: jdev.recipehelper, PID: 27305
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class EditText
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at jdev.recipehelper.IngredientAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(IngredientAdapter.java:41)
    at jdev.recipehelper.IngredientAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(IngredientAdapter.java:18)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17536)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17536)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5478)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17536)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5478)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17536)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5478)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17536)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5478)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17536)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5478)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17536)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5478)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2629)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17536)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2102)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1218)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1435)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1106)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6018)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:792)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:596)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:557)
    at androi
E/ActivityManager: App crashed! Process: jdev.recipehelper
```

Activity(just in case):

```
package jdev.recipehelper;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by dracc on 21/04/2016.
 */
public class IngredientAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IngredientAdapter.IngredientHolder>{
    // Adapter personalizado que usaremos para mostrar los ingredientes en la calculadora, por el momento no funciona.

    // Instanciamos la activity para poder acceder a sus metodos.
    private Calculator calc;
    // Dataset que usara.
    private ArrayList<Ingredient> data;


    // Constructor que define el dataset
    public IngredientAdapter(ArrayList<Ingredient> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    // Constructor con dataset y activity
    public IngredientAdapter(Calculator calc, ArrayList<Ingredient> data) {
        this.calc = calc;
        this.data = data;
    }

    // Creamos el IngredientHolder con el layout seleccionado
    @Override
    public IngredientHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ingredient_card, parent, false);
        return new IngredientHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final IngredientHolder holder, final int position) {
        Ingredient item = data.get(position);
        holder.setIngText(item);
        holder.quantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            }
        });
        holder.quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                setQuantities(position, data, holder);
            }
        });
    }


    // Importante pedirle a este metodo que nos devuelva el tamaño del array, o no creara ni una card
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    // Con este metodo modificamos la cantidad del resto de ingredientes y actualizamos el coste total.
    private void setQuantities(int position, ArrayList<Ingredient> data, IngredientHolder holder){
        float qprev = data.get(position).getQuantity();
        float qnext;
        float mult;

        try{
            qnext = Float.parseFloat(holder.quantity.getText().toString());
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            qnext = 1;
        }
        if (qnext == 0){
            qnext = 1;
        }
        mult = qnext/qprev;
        for (int i = 0; i<data.size(); i++){
            Ingredient e = data.get(i);
            e.setQuantity(e.getQuantity()*mult);
            Log.d("TAG", e.getName() + " " + e.getQuantity());
            data.set(i, e);
            try{
                notifyItemChanged(i);
            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.d("peta", "setQuantities: " + ex);
            }
        }
        Log.d("TAG","mult: " + mult +" Siguiente");

        calc.setCostText(data);
    }

    // IngredientHolder personalizado con el que manejaremos los elementos necesarios del layout
    public static class IngredientHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        // Componentes a los que accederemos.
        TextView name;
        EditText quantity;

        // Constructor para inicializar los distintos componentes
        public IngredientHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvrecname);
            quantity = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etingquantity);
        }

        // Set para modificar todos los campos de la carta a la vez
        public void setIngText(Ingredient item){
            name.setText(item.getName());
            quantity.setText(Float.toString(item.getQuantity()));
        }

        public void setQuantityText(Ingredient e) {
            this.quantity.setText("" + e.getQuantity());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: pure speculation - try to uninstall (completely) the app from the phone and try again.

Comment: @Tomer just tried, but doesn't work, anyway i have this problem since the first test on phone, thanks anyway :P

Comment: What are the API levels of your emulator and your phone?

Comment: @GuilhermeP phone API is 21, emulator api is 23, app should be compatible with 15+
Just tried to use the appcompat EditText, but still crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer works for me:
[@Abdullah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37839988)

Seems like a problem with my alpha gradle.

Thanks for the help guys.