# Android Studio - Error inflating class EditText

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have been trying to solve this problem for a full day now. I created a new project in Android Studio and chose the tab navigation activity. From there I added a simple EditText in the XML of fragment_main.xml and run it. It always gives me an EditText inflation error. This does not happen with any other element e.g. TextViews

fragment_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="packagename.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/editText3" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
}
```

Logcat:

```
Process: <package name>, PID: 20764
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class EditText
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
  at <package name>.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:119)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2622)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2030)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1399)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5845)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The only thing I changed was adding an EditText to the fragment_main.xml after creating the project with a tab navigation activity. None of the Java was changed. Also where you see "package name", this is actually my full package name, I just removed it for this question for privacy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: missed > in root layout

Comment: My mistake, I removed the package name when asking the question, the > is there in the code. I have edited the question

Comment: clean and rebuild the project

Comment: The application still crashes with the same error

Comment: show your java file code

Comment: Updated question with MainActivity.java - although I made no changes to this after creating the project

Comment: what is your packagename?

Comment: issue is with your MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment

Comment: com.myname.myprojectname - that isn't the problem though, I just omitted it for privacy

Comment: @KDeogharkar could you elaborate? This was given to me as default by Android Studio when creating the project

Comment: set proper path of your activity in"tools:context" in your xml or remove that line..

Comment: try to remove tool:context temporary and check

Comment: @Mehta the path is currently com.myname.myprojectname.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment how should I change this?

Comment: set that path and try to run or remove that line temporary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same bug just recently. Apparently, the problem is that Gradle 2.2-alpha* doesn't know how to handle `EditText`'s nine-patch images properly. Especially one that is located in `res/drawable-v21/abc_edit_text_material.xml`. This is a currently open issue in code.google [[Reference]](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210467)

The solution is simple, just downgrade Gradle version to `2.1` for now instead of `2.2-alpha2` or even `2.2-alpha3`. It worked perfectly for me when I did this.

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, solved this a while back by downgrading. I will accept your answer :)